# Select time from today

Tags: sqlite

I am struggeling with a SQLite query.

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE "timings" ( `id` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `time` text NOT NULL, `timestamp` INTEGER )
```

Now, I want to read the entry with the lowest time from a day.
In the attached picture, I want to read row with id = 3

I have tried different querys for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT time FROM timings

SELECT time, MAX(timestamp) FROM timings WHERE time > '21.11.2018 00:00:00'
```

but my WHERE is anyhow wrong.

Maybe has someone an idea?

[SQlite Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykilt.jpg)

Comment: Did you tried SELECT MIN(time) FROM timings

Comment: yes, I tried also MIN() time and MAX() time. Unfortunately, SELECT MIN(time) FROM timings return the oldest entry. It could happen, that the entry is not the latest and not the first.

Comment: No, SQLite is not supporting DateTime format.

Comment: Use this SELECT TOP 1 * from timings ORDER BY time  DESC

Comment: Ya @HAmza Haider Is Right Try his query in SQLLite

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * from timings ORDER BY time DESC is correct, please try this

Comment: The format you're using for a time string cannot be meaningfully compared or ordered.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an syntax error near 1, when I try: SELECT TOP 1 * from timings ORDER BY time DESC

Comment: I tested this: SELECT * FROM timings ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1 this is returning the wrong entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

I decided to delete all entries they are not from today:

```
"DELETE FROM timings WHERE time < '" + yesterDay.ToString() + "'";
```

Then I can be sure, that only entries from today are in the SQlite database.
After that I do the following:

```
Select MIN(timestamp) FROM timings
```

This will return my oldest value.

Thanks for your support ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the Below code in Your SqlLite query the code is worked for you:

```
select time from timings WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = date('now') ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have tested this. The result is 0 rows